# Why is conversion from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 not the same in Windows and Linux?

Tags: java, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have the following in code to convert from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in a jar file and when I execute this jar in Windows I get one result and in CentOS I get another. Might anyone know why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {

    String x = "Ã„, Ã¤, Ã‰, Ã©, Ã–, Ã¶, Ãœ, Ã¼, ÃŸ, Â«, Â»";

    Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(x.getBytes());
    CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);

    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = iso88591charset.encode(data);
    byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();

    String z = new String(outputData);

    System.out.println(z);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

In Windows, java -jar test.jar > test.txt creates a file containing:
Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »

but in CentOS I get:
�?, ä, �?, é, �?, ö, �?, ü, �?, «, »

Comment: The � character represents an unprintable character (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29) perhaps your CentOS encoding is different then Windows?

Comment: What is it that you are really trying to do? Why do you have `"Ã„, Ã¤, Ã‰, Ã©, Ã–, Ã¶, Ãœ, Ã¼, ÃŸ, Â«, Â»";` that needs to be converted if you could just have `"Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »"` that needs no conversion at all? If these are not string literals in your source file, then you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines

```
x.getBytes());

String z = new String(outputData);
```

are platform and default encoding specific.

---

This runs as expect on Windows and Linux by avoiding platform specific conversions.

```
String x = "Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »";

Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(x.getBytes(utf8charset));
CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);

ByteBuffer outputBuffer = iso88591charset.encode(data);
byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();

String z = new String(outputData, iso88591charset);

System.out.println(z);
```

prints

```
Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »
```

Comment: Sorry but what is the point of this code? You already started with the correct end result and the code does absolutely nothing useful. It is exactly the same as `System.out.println(x);` right after declaring `x`

Comment: @Esailija Best to ask the OP that.  The code starts with characters which are encoded back and forth to two different encodings.  The only difference is that he has a pseudo-encded string which when called with getBytes() with the default encoding can be decoded with UTF-8.  That is clearly platform dependant.

Comment: @Esailija: Maybe the bytes are being transmitted between apps. This is likely just example code that demonstrates the same problem within a single app.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not following, this answer demonstrates precisely nothing. It has a string literal, that is then encoded as utf-8, and the result is decoded back in utf-8. I.E. a do nothing at all. After this, the same process is repeated, but with ISO-8859-1. Again, a complete no-operation (At best this operation specifically will lead to information loss but yea). No-operation is not platform specific.

Comment: @Esailija "No-operation is not platform specific" that is the point of my answer.  If having platform specific code is an issue for you (as the OS states), this is how you can change it so it is not platform specific.

Comment: @PeterLawrey but since the code doesn't do anything, what is gained from not being platform specific? I mean, `1+1` is not platform specific, but why would I post that as an answer. You can replace the whole snippet with `System.out.println("Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »");` and it will work exactly the same.

Comment: @Esailija The whole point of the question, as I understand it, is to show which methods are causing the original issue and how you can change the code so this doesn't happen. If being platform specific wasn't the issue, I have missed the point of the question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, this works on every platform, it's just that if the OP runs this code on *his input*, the result is `Ã?, Ã¤, Ã?, Ã©, Ã?, Ã¶, Ã?, Ã¼, Ã?, Â«, Â»` (The ascii question marks are from the lossy ISO conversion in this code) on every platform, rather than `Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »`

Comment: @Esailija What you have as the "result" is his input which when encoded on windows with the platform default encoding can be decoded with UTF-8 but on Centos cannot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20990/discussion-between-esailija-and-peter-lawrey)

Comment: @Esailija chat is blocked for me at the moment. ;)

Comment: :P Anyway, I am usually in javascript room, if you want to discuss this some time.

Answer (score 2):

You should first and foremost get the string in correct internal representation in java before even thinking about output. I.E. it should be that:

```
z.equals("Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »") == true
```

The above can be verified without any output encoding issues, because it simply prints `true` or `false`.

In Windows you already achieved this with

```
ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(x.getBytes());
CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);
```

Because all you need to go from `"Ã„, Ã¤, Ã‰, Ã©, Ã–, Ã¶, Ãœ, Ã¼, ÃŸ, Â«, Â»"` to `"Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »"` is:

```
ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(x.getBytes( windows1252/*explicit windows1252 works on CentOS too*/));
CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);
```

After this you do something with ISO-8859-1, which is futile because barely half the characters in your original string
can be represented in ISO-8859-1 not to mention you are already done as per above. You can delete the code after `utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer)`

So now your code could look like:

```
String x = "Ã„, Ã¤, Ã‰, Ã©, Ã–, Ã¶, Ãœ, Ã¼, ÃŸ, Â«, Â»";

Charset windows1252 = Charset.forName("Windows-1252");
Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

byte[] bytes = x.getBytes(windows1252);
String z = new String(bytes, utf8charset);

                                //Still wondering why you didn't just have this literal to begin with
                                //Check that the strings are internally equal so you know at least that
                                //the code is working

System.out.println(z.equals( "Ä, ä, É, é, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß, «, »")); 
System.out.println(z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities spring to mind:

- The encoding you're *actually* using for your source code may differ by platform
- The encoding the compiler *expects* by default may differ by platform (you can specify it on the command line)
- The platform default encoding used when you call `x.getBytes()` may differ by platform

It's not clear in what way you're trying to convert from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 - because your *original* data is actually just a `String`. You're treating the results of calling `x.getBytes()` *as if* it were UTF-8-encoded data, but it's just whatever the platform default is...

Likewise when you write:

```
String z = new String(outputData);
```

... that's using the platform default encoding. Don't do that.

You don't need the byte buffer stuff at all: just encode using `text.getBytes(encoding)` and decode using `new String(data, encoding)`.