# How to decode a utf string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encoding, character

I have been trying to decode the following string:

```
CrÃ©dit
```

in c# using the following code:

```
    Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
    string msg = iso.GetString(utf8.GetBytes(@"CrÃ©dit"));
```

which is yielding:

```
CrÃÂ©dit
```

I looked online  http://jeppesn.dk/utf-8.html and this is in correct utf 8 and should yield:

```
Crédit
```

Can someone please point out where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the other way around, and Windows-1252, not ISO-8859-1. Depending on context, people usually mean Windows-1252 when they say Latin-1 or ISO-8859-1, but actually using ISO-8859-1 will fail when there are characters like `€` because it was a mislabeling in the first place. Even browsers use Windows-1252 when ISO-8859-1 is specified as encoding.

```
Encoding w1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
string msg = utf8.GetString(w1252.GetBytes(@"CrÃ©dit"));
```

Comment: Given that none of the characters involved is in the "hole" here (0x80-0x9F) I believe the Windows-1252/ISO-8859-1 part is a red herring. (The more important thing is that this is basically a fundamentally broken approach.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah I know, I just always preach it anyway. What if he tried with `Ã€` next ([they always do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824859/why-is-conversion-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-not-the-same-in-windows-and-linux/13825027#13825027))? Then we'd have another question ..

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do something that doesn't make sense, basically. You should almost never<sup>1</sup> be interpreting the output of one encoding as the input to another encoding. It's like saying, "Suppose I save this image as a gif... then load that file using a jpeg loader... what does it look like?"

I *suspect* that if you use:

```
// Just an example: don't actually do this.
string msg = utf8.GetString(iso.GetBytes(@"CrÃ©dit"));
```

... it will do what you want, but you *shouldn't be doing this at all*.

Now, what is your *real* input (in what form) and what are you trying to achieve?

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're doing so, it's usually because someone else has already done the wrong thing, or there's a configuration problem somewhere. If you find yourself doing this, you should think very carefully about whether you should *really* be doing it, or whether you're just working around a different problem which should be tackled differently.

Comment: While the op seems to do this just out of curiosity, there is plenty of real use cases for *You should never be interpreting the output of one encoding as the input to another encoding*. Such as [repairing and restorng seriously screwed up transfers of text](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) I believe there is even a reference to cyrillic encoding screwups in a simpsons episode :P

Comment: @Esailija: Well repairing broken data is basically acknowledging that someone before you has done exactly what I've said you should never do... and if you *are* doing this for repair purposes, it's highly likely that you've already lost data.

Comment: Well I took it you meant that one should never write code like this. Broken data is not an acknowledgement that code like this was written at all. There are plenty of other ways the broken data will happen without code like this.

Comment: @Esailija: Well, you'd have to show me the *exact* situation... normally I'd try to get directly at the stored *binary* data if at all possible. I'll edit to "almost never" if that makes you happier though.

Comment: @Esailija: Yes, that sounds like interpreting character data which has been saved in one encoding as if it were saved in a different encoding. Avoid doing that, too :)

Comment: I guess you're right... I should play another angle; that it's not an ideal world and this just happens and that's life. And then you write code like this to repair it, well not specifically this code, but see the link in my first comment. But I am happy now with the edit :)