# How to unescape &#xfc; to ü?

Tags: java, escaping, xml-entities

I would like to unescape a XML character entity reference `&#xfc;` to `ü` in Java.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question has completely nothing to do with character encoding. The `&#xfc;` is just a XML entity, which is an ASCII-safe escaped form of an Unicode codepoint. I removed the encoding/decoding tags from the question as they would only generate incorrect answers from people who know nothing about the matters.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need an additional library to convert that codes to Unicode chars, like [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). This library has the class [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

public class Unescape {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#xfc;");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ü
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try encoding it as below:

```
try
    {
        String str = "üxy";
        final String s = new String(str, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824859/why-is-conversion-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-not-the-same-in-windows-and-linux

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The `&#xfc;` is a [hexadecimal XML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), not some [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) or whatever you incorrectly thought it was (your answer does basically not solve anything related to character encoding).

Comment: Did you create another account to upvote yourself or so? I can't imagine why someone would upvote this nonsensicial answer.